# AWS ECS weird docker behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, docker, port, amazon-ecs

I'm fairly new with Amazon's EC2 service, and I'm at a loss with the weird behavior I'm getting from it.
I have a Docker image that runs flawlessly when ran locally. I have uploaded it to a repository and made a cluster/service/task definition to run it in EC2.
When I attempt to curl to my running service, I'm told the connection refused (as I assume the port is not opened or mapped correctly).
If I ssh into Amazon EC2 and start the image manually with the -p 1200:1200 flag, it again runs without a problem and can be curled without error.

In addition to this, when I try to retrieve the logs from the image that amazon automatically deploys, they are empty.
When running this locally or manually on EC2, the logs exist and are correct. My inbound and outbound rules are not an issue to my knowledge, and my port mappings are set correctly as far as I know as well.

I've included screenshots of all of the described behavior, as well as a copy of my Dockerfile.

stopping amazon's running image and starting it manually with -p 1200:1200:
(after doing this, my service responds to curl)

[image: image being ran manually]

logs from doing so:

[image: logs from running manually]

empty logs from EC2 running the image:

[image: logs when ran from ec2]

inbound rules:

[image: inbound rules]

outbound rules:

[image: outbound rules]

port mappings:

[image: port mappings]

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM thedarbear/facerec

    EXPOSE 1200

    RUN mkdir -p /facerec
    WORKDIR /facerec
    COPY . /facerec
    RUN cd /facerec
    CMD python3 -u server.py
```

local inspect:

https://pastebin.com/7Y48ukqa

ec2 inspect:

https://pastebin.com/EdJRSEpi

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide or compare for us, both: `docker inspect <container-id>`?

Answer (score 0):

I see the difference in the docker images listed.

ECS is running the one that reads `<none>` and you are manually running the one that reads `latest`.

So, update your task definition adding `:latest` in the image field. Then update your service to use that task definition.

Also, remove manually the problematic image `docker rmi -f 4e1b63e39c66`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. The task is now updated to use the latest image, and the problematic image is deleted. Although I do think this was an issue that needed fixing, the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you re deployed the task? You need to update the service accordingly. In the task screen, hit Update service

Comment: yes, when I do so it says "Service: nothing to update"

Comment: Appart of this. I recommend to always use specific versions instead of : latest.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I've just recently started working with ec2 so I don't know good practice yet. In the meantime I've added the inspect of the two containers. One difference I noticed is attachstdout, perhaps this is why one shows logs and the other doesn't?

Comment: They looks fine. The main difference I can see is the different base images ids. A big difference. Try to get your task running the latest image

Comment: See the field Image. They are different

Comment: I see, I'll look into that

Comment: yes, the Image fields now both display "6f7...4d", but only the local one responds to curl and only the local one has non-empty logs